# Getting native resolution on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: display, display-resolution

EDIT: I Managed to get 1080p working after using 1920 1080 59 instead of 60 :)

I have a 22 inch LCD TV connected to my PC (IntelHD 4400 graphics) via VGA a cable. On windows the TV works fine on native 1080p resolution. But on Ubuntu (16.04) the resolution is set to 1600x900 and I can't change it to 1080p. Only useable resolution available is 1360x768 but it would be great if I can set this up to its native resolution. I got the full resolution when I tried with friend's graphics card (ATI 5450) but I want to make this work without getting extra hardware. I've tried this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions but I get this error: `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed`

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

VGA1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm

   1920x1080     58.94 +
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
   1920x1080_59.00  58.94* 

VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: You seem to have found the solution yourself. It's that correct? If you don't mind: Post the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Managed to get 1080p working after using `1920 1080 59` instead of `60`.

Comment: Would accept your own answer as it is the one that works for you.  See https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the limits of VGA at that resolution , it would be better to use HDMI or display port if you can.

Comment: My motherboard doesn't have a HDMI port, I will try with the DVI-D port.

Comment: Dvi-d would definitely help, its got way more bandwidth than VGA.